# How is $\frac{4\times 3+5\times 6}{18\times -22} = 3$?

Tags: arithmetic

I was preparing for civil services tests and recently came across this question in a book.

[image]

Its answer is option C as given in that book.

I have tried to solved it by following DMAS rule and also not following DMAS rule, but I could not get it equal to 3.

How is this possible?

Comment: I think the answer is wrong.

Comment: The expression is invalid. Probably, it is a typo.

Comment: Whoever composed this problem should have their math license revoked.

Comment: I am studying formal languages in computer science and the only part of this expression that I think would be problematic for a basic recursive definition of Arithmetic Expressions is the $18 * -22$ part since -22 should be in brackets, otherwise the denominator should evaluate the multiplications first I believe.

Comment: The expression is of course **not** invalid, but the answer is not in the choices: it's $$-\dfrac{7}{66}$$

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut It IS invalid, the signs "x" and "-" are never allowed to occur in a row. The parenthesis are missing.

Comment: Ah, I did't think about that, as most programming languages would accept this. Thanks.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut This is correct, apparently to support lazy or careless users :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{4\times 3+5\times 6}{18\times 2 -22}=\frac{42}{14}=3$$
So the original expression is probably a typo for the above.

Comment: or maybe $18-2^2$, but your guess seems simpler

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$\frac{4\cdot 3+5\cdot 6}{18\cdot -22}=-\frac{42}{396}=-\frac{7}{66}$$

maybe the original problem was

$$\frac{4\cdot 3+5\cdot 6}{18-(2^2)}=\frac{42}{14}=3$$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I don't know the level of the asker, I have no prejudices about this, simply I try to give a good help for the posed OP. That's all.

Comment: Wow! Well done with finding an expression that matches the answer!

Comment: @MattiP. Thanks, also Lord Shark has found a good explanation.